# Map serial port data into integer

Tags: python, dictionary, serial-port

I am intending to retrieve a string from arduino through serial port. How do I map the string into an integer/float? Here's my current code using Python. What I would want to achieve is to be able to read the first value as a number.

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM7', 9600)

try:
    result=ser.readline()
    pieces=result.split(" \t")
    map(float, pieces)
    print pieces
    if pieces[0] == 5.0:
        print "Yes"
    else:
        print "No"
except:
    print "Failed to get data from Arduino!"
```

Results:

```
[5.0, 23.2, 88.17]
['5', '23.20', '88.17\r\n']
No
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to assign map to a variable, or in this case `pieces`:

```
pieces = map(float, pieces) #assign the floated list to the variable 'pieces'
```

Other than using map, there's another alternative too :)

Well, here is an alternative:

```
#List comprehension:
pieces = [float(i) for i in pieces]
```

Looks just as nice, right?

In short, here is what your code should look like:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM7', 9600)

try:
    result=ser.readline()
    pieces=result.split(" \t")
    pieces = map(float, pieces)
    print pieces
    if pieces[0] == 5.0:
        print "Yes"
    else:
        print "No"
except:
    print "Failed to get data from Arduino!"
```

Hope this helps!